# IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() and IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() why they don't have new keyword

Tags: c#, .net

In .net this is how `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are defined. If you define something like this (for example IMyInterface and IMyInterface) you get a warning to add `new` in front of your method, how that is possible?

(I know for implementing I have to implement it explicitly, I just asking about definign interfaces even with no implementation)

```
public interface IEnumerable
    {
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }

public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
    {
        IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Example

```
public interface IMy
    {
        IQueryable GetAll();
    }

public interface IMy<T> : IMy
    {
         IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that it's not [declared with new](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,35)?

Comment: You can't declare a new IEnumerable or a new IMy.  You have to define a class that uses that interface and declare that new.

Comment: It's worth noting the "new" keyword in this particular case does nothing from a compilation perspective. It's simply meant to get rid of the compiler warning. In other words, the compiler is saying "beware, you are hiding a member" and you are telling the compiler "I know I am hiding it, don't warn me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324279/ienumerable-getenumerator-and-ienumerablet-getenumerator-why-they-dont-ha/43324700#comment73713050_43324279) already, it *does* have the `new` keyword associated to it.

From the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,40):

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    // Returns an IEnumerator for this enumerable Object.  The enumerator provides
    // a simple way to access all the contents of a collection.
    /// <include file='doc\IEnumerable.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="IEnumerable.GetEnumerator"]/*' />
    new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

If you let Visual Studio create a stub for it, it will indeed not have a `new` keyword. That is up to you.

Comment: Shouldn't this question just be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"?

Comment: That's fine with me too. I just saw 2 deleted answers and I thought it needs one. If OP wants, he can even delete it.

Comment: @DavidG I keep the question in case somebody else has same question in future

Comment: @RezaRahmati I don't really mind the question being here, I just think it should be closed rather than answered.